# Human readable, recursive, sorted list of largest files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, posix

What is the best practice for printing a top 10 list of largest files in a POSIX shell? There has to be something more elegant than my current solution:

```
DIR="."
N=10
LIMIT=512000

find $DIR -type f -size +"${LIMIT}k" -exec du {} \; | sort -nr | head -$N | perl -p -e 's/^\d+\s+//' | xargs -I {} du -h {}
```

where LIMIT is a file size threshold to limit the results of find.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Yes (see the script above). The problem is that `du` doesn't sort the results.

Comment: Given a random block on a filesystem, is it possible to find the filename associated with it? (For those blocks that are in a file/directory). If so, that would be a very efficient way to find the very biggest files. (I'm pretty sure the answer is No, I googled before, but maybe SO will find something.) Filesystem-dependent?

Answer (score 7):

Edit:

Using Gnu utilities (`du` and `sort`):

```
du -0h | sort -zrh | tr '\0' '\n'
```

This uses a null delimiter to pass information between `du` and `sort` and uses `tr` to convert the nulls to newlines. The nulls allow this pipeline to process filenames which may include newlines. Both `-h` options cause the output to be in human-readable form.

Original:

This uses `awk` to create extra columns for sort keys. It only calls `du` once. The output should look exactly like `du`.

I've split it into multiple lines, but it can be recombined into a one-liner.

```
du -h |
  awk '{printf "%s %08.2f\t%s\n", 
    index("KMG", substr($1, length($1))),
    substr($1, 0, length($1)-1), $0}' |
  sort -r | cut -f2,3
```

Explanation:

- BEGIN - create a string to index to substitute 1, 2, 3 for K, M, G for grouping by units, if there's no unit (the size is less than 1K), then there's no match and a zero is returned (perfect!)
- print the new fields - unit, value (to make the alpha-sort work properly it's zero-padded, fixed-length) and original line
- index the last character of the size field
- pull out the numeric portion of the size
- sort the results, discard the extra columns

Try it without the `cut` command to see what it's doing.

Edit:

Here's a version which does the sorting within the AWK script and doesn't need cut (requires GNU AWK (`gawk`) for `asorti` support):

```
du -h0 |
   gawk 'BEGIN {RS = "\0"}
        {idx = sprintf("%s %08.2f %s", 
         index("KMG", substr($1, length($1))),
         substr($1, 0, length($1)-1), $0);
         lines[idx] = $0}
    END {c = asorti(lines, sorted);
         for (i = c; i >= 1; i--)
           print lines[sorted[i]]}'
```

Edit: Added null record separation in order to handle potential filenames which include newlines. Requires GNU `du` and `gawk`.

Comment: `awk: calling undefined function asorti
 input record number 75, file 
 source line number 5`

Comment: @AlexeySh.: Sorry, I will change my answer to point out that GNU AWK (`gawk`) is required for `asorti`.