# awk syntax errors with double star **

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'm using Debian 6 and GNU sed, trying to get awk to convert the output of `du` from a long string of bytes to a more human readable number with suffixes like Mb and Kb. (I know you can use the `-h` option, but I want to do this manually with awk.)

So far, my command looks like this (I put in the newlines to make it more readable):

```
du /test.img | grep [0-9]* | awk "{ sum=$1 ; hum[1024**3]='Gb';hum[1024**2]='Mb';
hum[1024]='Kb'; for (x=1024**3; x>=1024; x/=1024){ if (sum>=x)
{ printf '%.2f %s\n',sum/x,hum[x];break } }}"
```

However, I get syntax errors from/near the double stars:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near *
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near *
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near *
awk: line 1: extra ')'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
```

If I make all double stars `**` just one star `*`, awk runs, but I get an incorrect number.

What can I do to fix these syntax errors and stop being so `awk`wardly confused? *ba dum tshh*

Comment: Are you trying to use `**` as an exponent? Isn't that `^`?

Comment: Ooops! You're right! That fixed it.

Comment: And those should be GiB, MiB, and KiB, as you're using binary kilobytes (2**10). To further clarify your code, you may as well pre-define your constants as variables, either through `awk -f GiB=...` or in a `BEGIN` block.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5213618/26428). By the way, rather than setting your suffixes for each line of input, you should set them once in a `BEGIN` block as Andrew suggests. You should also use single quotes for the outer set and double quotes where you have single ones. If you need to pass a shell variable into the awk script, you should use: `awk -v` (but I don't think that applies here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to make it "official" (as an answer)...

You're using `**` for exponentiation. In `awk`, the `^` operator is used for exponentiation. I imagine there are many references on the internet, but the one I found is [here](http://www.bo.infn.it/alice/alice-doc/mll-doc/linux/scripts/node46.html).

Comment: But Debian's default awk is `mawk`, oops.