# how to compute power value with bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

We want to calculate  2^(3.0) and 2^(-3.0). thanks.

```
!/bin/bash
c=3.0
g=-3.0
c=$((2**$c)) #syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
g=$((2**$g)) #syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
echo "c=$c"
echo "g=$g"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash's built-in arithmetic only operates on integers, and doesn't allow a negative exponent for the `**` operator.

There are a variety of other tools available that can perform floating-point arithmetic. For example:

```
$ c=3.0
$ g=-3.0
$ awk "BEGIN{print $c ^ $c}"
27
$ awk "BEGIN{print $c ^ $g}"
0.037037
$ perl -e "print $c ** $c, qq(\n), $c ** $g, qq(\n)"
27
0.037037037037037
```

To store the result in a variable:

```
$ c=$(awk "BEGIN{print $c ^ $c}")
$ echo $c
27
```

In Awk, `^` is the exponentiation operator (which could be confusing to C programmers, since C's `^` operator is bitwise xor). Perl uses `^` for bitwise xor, like C, and `**` for exponentiation. GNU Awk (gawk) supports `**` as an exponentiation operator as an extension, but the use of that extension should be avoided in portable code.

Comment: I was just bitten by this so wanted to share an answer from another awk exponentiation question: the POSIX standard for exponentiation is ^, so that should be used for maximum portability instead of **. (Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913440/199475 and citation for POSIX is the bottom of https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html ).

Comment: @carbocation Interesting, I didn't know that. Since awk's expressions are so similar to C's, and C uses `^` for bitwise xor, it could be a little confusing, but you're right. (gawk defines functions for bitwise operations. POSIX awk doesn't support bitwise operations.)

Answer (score 1):

Good answers already in the thread using perl and awk. We can also use python:

```
python -c "from sys import argv as a; print(pow(int(a[1]), int(a[2])))" 2 6
```

#### For reuse:

```
alias pow='python -c "from sys import argv as a; print(pow(int(a[1]), int(a[2])))"'
pow 2 6
pow 2 -2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<257; i++ ))
  do
    h=`echo  2^"$i" |bc -l`;
    echo -e -n $i "  " '\t'
    echo  $h  |tr -d -c [0-9] |rev |sed -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\1,/g' |rev | sed 's/^,//';
  done
exit 0
```

Comment: prints the powers of 2 from 1 to 256, with commas

Comment: Could you edit and provide more details? Perhaps try explaining what the code does in English. Your post was flagged for its length and content. Consider revising to avoid deletion. (review team)